# Videogular2: mute functionality is not working in iphone, ipad

Tags: angular, videogular

We have integrated Videogular2 library into our Angular 7 Project. Everything works fine in Desktop for both Chrome and Safari. But when i tested the same in Iphone and iPad, Mute functionality is not working. It's working fine in Android Device.

After video start playing, if i click mute icon, i am still hearing Volume sound and icon is still showing as unmuted in UI.

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
          <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
          <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
          <vg-controls>
            <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
            <vg-playback-button></vg-playback-button>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
            <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>
            <vg-mute vgFor="singleVideo" (click)="betterMute(media)"></vg-mute>
            <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
          </vg-controls>
          <video #media [vgMedia]="media" id="singleVideo" preload="auto" playsinline>
            <source src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
  </vg-player>
```

I also tried attaching click event to the vg-mute component.By setting volume to '0' I can't able to hear sound, but still icon is showing as 'unmuted' in UI.

```
betterMute(media) {
    console.log(this.api);
    console.log(this.target);
    if (typeof this.target['muted'] === 'undefined' || this.target['muted'] === false) {
      this.target['muted'] = true;
      this.target.elem.muted = true;
      this.api.volume = 0;
      this.target.volume = 0;
    } else {
      this.target['muted'] = false;
      this.target.elem.muted = false;
      this.api.volume = 1;
      this.target.volume = 1;
    }
  }
```

[image]

**Version**

Videogular2: 6.4.0 
Angular: 7 
Safari: 12 
Mac OS: 10

Answer (score 0):

Insert the tag below after `<vgMute>`:

```
<vg-volume vgFor="singleVideo"></vg-volume>
```

Comment: <vg-volume vgFor="singleVideo" ></vg-volume>